# Is it possible to get the speed of a file transfer using Apache?

Tags: javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest, 360-virtual-reality, delightvr

I'm working on a 360 degree video streaming app. I'm currently passing HLS fragments from S3 via Apache proxying to the client, to get around an iOS bug where CORS headers aren't checked for video textures. I want to monitor how much data is being sent to the user, so that I can provide feedback to the user about when they can expect their video playback to start.

Say the user loads /video.php, which makes an XHR call to /video/video1.ts which is 20mb. Is it possible to match up the two requests in PHP or on the command line, even just by IP address, to be able to pass progress messages back to the user? I'd love to be able to say "5mb / 20mb downloaded" -- even if it's still not quite possible to predict exactly when the HLS playback will start.

As far as I know, there's no way to tell how much progress has been made or when the HLS playback will begin -- I'm using Delight VR but they've said they don't get any access to that data from the browser.

Thanks heaps for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way will be to use a PHP script to proxy the file and store progress in a session variable.

This is a snippet of one approach from https://coolcodings.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/track-file-downloading-progress-with-javascript/

```
$file = @fopen("SET YOUR DOWNLOADING FILE PATH HERE","rb");
$fileSize = filesize("SET YOUR DOWNLOADING FILE PATH HERE");
$fileName = "SET FILE NAME";

header('Content-Type: SET YOUR MIME TYPE');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Length: '.$fileSize); 
while(!feof($file)) {
        echo fread($file, 1024*8);
        ob_flush();
        flush();     
        $downloadedBytes+= (1024 * 8);


        session_start();
        $_SESSION['current_file_downloaded_bytes'] = $downloadedBytes;
        session_commit();
}
```